# Click once deployment -  will a lower version get downloaded?

Tags: winforms, clickonce

I am using VS2010 and deploying a small winforms type application - using click once deployment strategy.

If the server has a lower version installed in it(when comparing with the version in the users Cache)., will it still get downloaded to users machine while clicking on the "Run" button of the webpage generated by Click once deployment.

I have set "Application available online only".

Comment: I am confused what are you asking ?

Comment: No Click once will always run the latest version

Comment: I got the answer with the below test. ie, I installed v1.0.1.0 in Server, then used it in a client, then I installed v1.0.2.0 in server, then used it in the same client, then v1.0.3.0 and used. Now I again installed v1.0.1.0 in server, still it got downloaded and worked.(Note Always i did a clean installation, ie,no old contents of previous installation will be present in server.) - What ever version in the server is considered as latest and it will be run, irrespective of the contents of the cache (Though the version in the cache is higher.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand that the assembly version and the Click once publish version are different

Assembly Version is stored in AssemblyVersion.cs or AssemblyVersion.vb

[Publish Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haeyaeba.aspx) is stored in the project properties

Comment: Yeah I got that. In my case I am maintaining same version number for both Publish and Assembly. BTW, Thanks for pointing the link about Publish version (I found the recommendation from Microsoft that never decrement the publish version.)